# Dynamic linq-to-sql that queries based on multiple keywords

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I had been putting together a simple little search.

```
IEnumerable<Member> searchResults = (from m in members
                                     where m.ScreenName.ToUpper().Contains(upperKeyword)
                                     select m).AsEnumerable();
```

An then I realized this if the user typed in "keyword1 keyword2", this little query will always search for that exact string. So, I decided I should probably split keywords

```
string[] keywords = upperKeyword.split(' ');
```

and then I ran into an issue. I can't really do this:

```
IEnumerable<Member> searchResults = (from m in members
                                     where m.ScreenName.ToUpper().Contains(keywords) // array of string
                                     select m).AsEnumerable();
```

because `.Contains()` doesn't take array. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
IEnumerable<Member> searchResults = members.ToList().Where(m => keywords.Any(k => m.Summary.Contains(k)))
```

**Edit**

Added .ToList(), as I don't think LINQ will be able to convert the above into SQL, so we'll have to perform this in-memory.

Comment: Huh... this looks really promising... just needed to add a `)` on the end. testing this now.

Comment: @quakkels - Yea it should do the trick, the only problem is there is probably a more efficient solution that will actually only pull those matching rows of data instead of pulling everything into memory and THEN filtering it down.

Comment: You shouldn't have to ToList() it. You should be able to directly reference the table and compare against it. But +1, this is the best solution for partial matching a list of values.

Comment: So close but no... raises this exception : `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.` I tried switching `Any` with `Contains` but then the error changes to say that the lambda could not conver to string

Comment: @quakkels - I figured as much, so I inserted .ToList() and that should work, though not optimally.

Comment: P.S. I also don't recommend this as nothing more than a brute force search.  I highly recommend implementing FULL TEXT search, if that is an option.

Comment: I added the `.ToList()`. At first glance it appeared to work. But something's not right. it seems to pick and choose which keywords or records to return

Comment: Then there may be another coding issue.  I would put the results of the .ToList() call in a separate variable and examine the contents of the collection to see what/when/why.

Comment: Thanks... I had forgotten to add a `.ToUpper()` to the query. I was converting the search parameters to uppercase earlier in the program and I forgot to account for that in this new linq. This works great... (of course, not optimized, but thanks for the help.)

Answer (score 1):

**For *Exact* Matches:**

Try the inverse of what you have: `where keywords.Contains(m.ScreenName)`

For reference, [Creating IN queries with LINQ-to-SQL](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/)

**For *Partial* Matches:**

```
string[] keywords = new[]{ ... };
var results = db.members.Where(m => keywords.Any(sn => m.ScreenName.Contains(sn)));
```

*No compilation error here, but I don't have the data to test against.*

Comment: Thanks for the link... unfortunately, reversing the query order will not logically work. `keywords` contains words that may be part of a `ScreenName`. Therefore, `keywords` will never contain `ScreenName`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @quakkels: You are correct, this would be for exact matching the list.

Comment: Thanks. If that need arises I'l know where to find the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the array to a list. I'm just on my way out of the office, but I think this should work.

```
IEnumerable<Member> searchResults = (from m in members
                                     where keywords.ToList().Contains(m.ScreenName.ToUpper()) // array of string
                                     select m).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `.Contains()` will only accept a `string` or a `char`.

Comment: @quakkels - I'm sorry, I think I have this wrong. I've edited my response.